# SIM5216 Command AT+CHTTPSSEND

Tags: http, https, arduino, command, 3g

I'm trying to receive data from a website using Arduino and Sim5216 3g board.

The AT+CHTTPSSEND requires the following information (Taken from the example in the SIM5216 manual)

"AT+CMMSSEND=88"

">GET  / HTTP/1.1 "

"Host:www.mywebsite.com"

"User-Agent: MY WEB AGENT "

"Content-Length: 0"

What is the "User-Agent"?  From what I searched, it represents the browser you are using.  I'm inclined to leave it blank, however when I do that, once I enter the command with the other info filled out, I get no response.  The sim5216 board doesn't respond anymore and I have to press the reset button to get any further responses from it (even if I type AT, I don't get an ok unless I reset the board).

Any comments/help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: To be clear, under Host, I have entered my dummy website "jockwr.000webhostapp.com/"

Comment: Unless you show us exactly what you are doing, we can't really help you.

Answer (score -1):

Check my tutorial [HTTPS GET request with SIM5215E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979593/https-get-request-with-sim5215e)!

Just don't care about User-Agent for now. It represents browser you are using, but it doesn't matter for success of GET request.